# Query an array of sub-documents where a field's value is same for all elements

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, mongodb

I need to find elements in a Mongo database collection with an array of objects as an element such that one field of all elements in that array have the same value.

The entries have this format:

```js
{"tag":
    {"tag": "val"},
    "tags":
        [{"foo": "val", "bar": int}, {"foo": "val", "bar": int}, {"foo": "val", "bar": int}]}
}
```

I am new to MongoDB, but looked up some stuff, and I've read `$and` and `$all` as well as `$in`, but none seem to do what I want.

Here is an example, with four documents:

```js
{"tag1":
    {"tag11": "val11"},
    "tags":
        [{"foo": "val", "bar": 1}, {"foo": "val", "bar": 2}, {"foo": "val3", "bar": 1}]}
}
{"tag1":
    {"tag11": "val21"},
    {"tags":
        [{"foo": "val4", "bar": 2}, {"foo": "val6", "bar": 2}, {"foo": "val3", "bar": 2}]}
}
{"tag1":
    {"tag11": "val21"},
    {"tags":
        [{"foo": "val4", "bar": 4}, {"foo": "val6", "bar": 2}, {"foo": "val3", "bar": 3}]}
}
{"tag1":
    {"tag11": "val21"},
    {"tags":
        [{"foo": "val5", "bar": 2}, {"foo": "val5", "bar": 2}, {"foo": "val5", "bar": 2}]}
}
```

I need a query to find all entries that have their `tags` array elements with a `bar` value of 2, for example. In the above example, it will return the 2nd and last one.

This would be the result:

```js
(2)
{"tag1":
    {"tag11": "val21"},
    {"tags":
        [{"foo": "val4", "bar": 2}, {"foo": "val6", "bar": 2}, {"foo": "val3", "bar": 2}]}
}
(4)
{"tag1":
    {"tag11": "val21"},
    {"tags":
        [{"foo": "val5", "bar": 2}, {"foo": "val5", "bar": 2}, {"foo": "val5", "bar": 2}]}
}
```

(#) are used to point out the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $elemMatch like this...

```
db.collections.find({tag1.tags: {$elemMatch: {tag1.tags.bar:2}})
```

Comment: The results I am getting are almost all elements with a `"bar": 2` element. Is there a way to make it check all elements in tags to have "bar": 2? Like it will only include it if all its tags had `"bar": 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Aggregation query to iterate over the `tags` array and find that all `tags.bar` values are same (for each document).

The example `foobar` collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "tags" : [ { "foo" : "val4", "bar" : 2 }, { "foo" : "val6", "bar" : 2 }, { "foo" : "val3", "bar" : 2 } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "tags" : [ { "foo" : "val2", "bar" : 3 }, { "foo" : "val3", "bar" : 2 }, { "foo" : "val4", "bar" : 2 } ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "tags" : [ { "foo" : "val2", "bar" : 2 }, { "foo" : "val3", "bar" : 2 }, { "foo" : "val4", "bar" : 9 } ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "tags" : [ { "foo" : "val2", "bar" : 4 }, { "foo" : "val3", "bar" : 4 }, { "foo" : "val4", "bar" : 4 } ] }
```

**The Query:**

```
db.foobar.aggregate( [ 
  { $addFields: { firstBar: {$arrayElemAt: [ "$tags.bar", 0 ] } } }, 
  { $addFields: { tagBarMatch: { $map: { 
                                   input: "$tags", 
                                      as: "tagEle", 
                                      in: { 
                                            $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$$tagEle.bar","$firstBar"  ] }, 
                                                     then: true, 
                                                     else: false 
                                                    } 
                                          }
   } } } }, 
  { $addFields: { tagBarMatch: { $allElementsTrue: [ "$tagBarMatch" ] } } },
  { $match: { tagBarMatch: true } },
  { $project: { _id: 1, tags: 1 } }
] )
```

**The Output:**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "tags" : [ { "foo" : "val4", "bar" : 2 }, { "foo" : "val6", "bar" : 2 }, { "foo" : "val3", "bar" : 2 } ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "tags" : [ { "foo" : "val2", "bar" : 4 }, { "foo" : "val3", "bar" : 4 }, { "foo" : "val4", "bar" : 4 } ] }
```